# What is the difference between @client.command and @commands.command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "", intents = discord.Intents.all())

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @client.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")
```

Both `@client.command()` and `@commands.command()` works, what does the differences actually ?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "", intents = discord.Intents.all())

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")
```

Comment: commands.command() is used within extensions, since the client isn't defined there. I don't believe there's any difference.

Comment: Adding to what Taku said, ```commands.command()``` is used in cogs.

Answer (score 0):

Using @client/bot.commands() is when you are using a file that isn't being called in a cog or another folder.

@commands.command() is when client/bot isn't defined also making it so in your async def parameter have to call client

Example:

```
@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Hey!")
```

Or for cogs:

```
@commands.command()
async def hi(client,ctx):
  await ctx.send("Hey")
```

Answer (score 0):

@client.command() is a command that can only be used in the main file (where client is defined)

@commands.command() is can be used in both cogs and the main file. This is way cleaner than a huge 3k lines long main file

Answer (score 0):

`@commands.command` is used to create a command while `@client.command` is to create and register one. `@commands.command()` is usually used in a cog, since the cog will register them when loaded.

`@client.command()` shouldn't be used in cogs. Since it's a shortcut for:

- `@commands.command()`
- `client.add_command`

it will be added twice (by the shortcut and the cog), and cause an error.